# CKEditor filtered HTML body field is not showing for non-administrator users when editing

Tags: wysiwyg

I am on drupal 7.56.

Something really disturbing happens.

I have created a **custom content type** named "**Information**" that uses the **default body field**. I granted access to this content to **Administrator** and to a newly created role that is "**editor**".

I made wrights configuration for both roles :

- "Editor" and "Administrator" can "**Edit own, Edit any**" information ;
- "Editor" and "Administrator" can "**Edit own, Edit any**" field body for that Information content type.

But only "Administrator" sees the body field in **editing mode**.

I am also using [field_permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and [content_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) modules to make sure everything is fine in detail.

**Still the same**. On any browser, "Administrator" can see the body in edit mode but not the editor. Notice that body field text shows normally when displaying the node(s).

A **help** will be welcome!

Comment: Sounds like you may have configured a filter that is not available to the editor. So, for example, the filter set on the body field is "Full HTML" but the editor does not have permission to use it.

Comment: I have granted permission for user "Editor" to have access on "filtered HTML" option. I did that in "admin/config/content/formats".

Comment: I did that a few day ago. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: You are at least 3 critical security updates behind. You should upgrade to [7.59](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.59)

Comment: Yeah like, forget this issue, and get updated. Beyond that, there is something about that text format that the user does not have permission to use. You also haven't specified which text format it is in the question.

Comment: Yes, after the updates, if a content item field was saved with a filter the editor does not have access to, they will not be able to edit that field. So as admin check the filter set on the field.

Comment: @Beebee I did follow the advice to update the core. I wanted the system to be ok about security. And it did solve the issue too. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong thanks a lot for that comment. It works now.

Comment: @mosgeorges good stuff. If I were you I'd check the site's codebase and database for any suspicious stuff just in case, since your site was left vulnverable to an actively exploited issue. Get professional help if you have to depending on how important your website is.

Comment: @Beebee thanx for the peace of advice. I'll be on it in a very few time.

Comment: @mosgeorges I have expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The commonest reason for this problem (and OP has confirmed it in this case) is as follows.

1. The field that is inaccessible to some users has a filtered text format
2. The formats that can be set on that field include one or more that are not permitted to all users (typically "full html")
3. The content item in question has been edited by a user that *has* access to the restricted format and they have saved it with the field set to that format.
4. Now only users that have that privilege can edit the item because that field won't load for those who don't.

The solution is for a privileged user to edit the item and change the format and save it again, though that *may* result in the HTML changing in a way that's undesirable. If the item needs "special" HTML then it may not be possible for it to be maintained by the less privileged users.